# Make Safari tab bar display all tabs at once without horizontal scrolling?

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

How can I make the Safari tab bar display all of the tabs?

Right now it displays only `n` tabs and the remaining are only accessible through a `>>` button.

How can I display all tabs at once without needing to scroll horizontally? Can tabs be set to shrink to a much smaller size, to display more at once?

Comment: How is this possible if, for example, you have more tabs than pixels?

Comment: @mankoff Surely you aren't being serious. If we had one tab per pixel we'd have about a thousand tabs (I'd have nearly 3000 on this machine here). As it is, Safari only lets you see about 10 tabs before they start stacking on the right. That is a factor of 100 difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually there is a plugin (not to be confused with an extension) called Glims which allows the tabs to have a minimum width roughly the size of the close button. It's free - [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims)

The screen resolution you are set to will ultimately determine your results, but for me I can normally only fit 13 tabs in a full screen Safari window. With Glims installed and this option turned on, it fits around 50 tabs. After that it resumes the usual behavior of giving you the >> for more tabs.

The drawback is obviously you loose your tab titles, making it difficult to discern one tab from another and this is why Apple chose to impose this arbitrary limitation. However there is another feature in Glims to display the website's favicon in the place where the close tab button usually is. This helps alleviate the aforementioned dilemma to an extent.

FYI - Glims does much more than that as well.

Comment: How can I enable Glims in safari? It downloaded `Glims Agent` but it does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try those following keys: Cmd + Shift + T but also chose go to view" Show Tab Bar.

If you are looking for a fresh app I recommand you to try the sweet **[Tabexposé](https://web.archive.org/web/20171007210722/http://www.cocoamug.com:80/tabexpose/index.html)** which works for Leopard as well as Snow Leopard

Comment: Re: TabExpose - Wow, that is cool! I was actually thinking about making something just like this the other day.

Comment: Yup! Sweet and fresh ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you already know you can click on the <kbd>**»**</kbd> to see the additional tabs.

Outside of that, your only other option is to make the browser window wider.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari 14 for macOS 11 Big Sur, tabs now shrink down to the size of their Favicon. This allows for many more tabs to be seen at once without horizontal scrolling.

[image: lots of tabs]